# Signing application in Visual Studio

Tags: winforms

I have a windows application project that has to be signed. I received the .spc and .pfx files from my client. I converted these files to .pfx and by right clicking an assembly - Properties - Signing I specified the .pfx file. Everything OK with no errors. The problem is that after compiling the assembly is not signed - the 'Digital Signature' tab when clicking 'Properties' is not present. I use VS 2008.
Do I miss something?
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Signing your assembly with a StrongName is NOT the same as providing your assembly with a digital signature. The signing you performed within Visual Studio is the former rather than the latter.

If you search Google (or your search engine of choice), you can find many places that discuss the differences between the two. For example:

- https://web.archive.org/web/20150905095237/http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2009/09/03/what-s-the-difference-part-five-certificate-signing-vs-strong-naming.aspx
- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/msdn-magazine/2006/july/clr-inside-out-using-strong-name-signatures

Comment: I've replaced it with some valid alternatives